# Woocommerce hook that fires after a product stock quantity is updated via REST API (clean cache)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I hope you can help me with this question I have.

I have Woocommerce that updates the stock quantity via REST API, however I use the caching plugin WP Fastest Cahe, and it only clears the product cache if it is manually updated by WP Admin (backend) when the API updates the amount of stock the plugin does not trigger the product cache clearing. They do however provide a hook for that purpose which is **//it clears the post with ID 1923
wpfc_clear_post_cache_by_id(1923);** the link that explains it all is this https://www.wpfastestcache.com/tutorial/delete-the-cache-by-calling-the-function/

I am not a programmer but does the code below work? What can I do to trigger the hook when there is the API update ?

Any tips?

I would be very grateful for some help :)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'remover_cache_produto', 10, 1 );
function remover_cache_produto($product_id) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        
        wpfc_clear_post_cache_by_id($product_id);  //clean cache
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `woocommerce_update_product` action hook, which fires when you are updating products from backend of wordpress as well from rest api.

So your function with the name `remover_cache_produto` executes when you are updating products via rest api. You are using the right action hook.

In your function you create a variable `$product`, which you are not using. So you can get rid of that line.

Put the code into the `functions.php` file of your theme or create a little wordpress plugin to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply :)

Great, the `woocommerce_update_product` hook is right :) My question is how do I trigger the function hook  `wpfc_clear_post_cache_by_id($post_id);` will changing the function name to wpfc_clear_post_cache_by_id work? And how do I get the product post_id for the hook? 

Sorry for these questions, as I have no idea how to run this function hook from the cache plugin.

Comment: Not working :(

`add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'remover_cache_produto', 10, 1 );
function remover_cache_produto($product_id) {
        
        wpfc_clear_post_cache_by_id($product_id);  //clean cache
    }`

Comment: You do not need to run it from the cache plugin. If you put the code in the functions.php file of your theme, it fires everytime a product gets updated. The argument is the product id, so you already have it. Maybe there is something wrong with the wpfc_clear_bla function. Try `var_dump($product_id)` when you update a product in backend to check if hook fires.

Comment: Yes, the Hook is fired, and I'm putting the code in funtions.php , the problem is that this code does not fire the function Hook already created by the caching plugin, do I have to put post_id instead of product_id ? Or is the plugin's hook call not being done right? Can you see the plugin link where it explains the Hook  https://www.wpfastestcache.com/tutorial/delete-the-cache-by-calling-the-function/

Comment: Product id is the same as post id, so it won't make any difference. But you can try setting the id by hand testing any product, by just entering the number instead of the variable. Maybe you should try clearing all the cache with minified too (as written in your link). otherwise you can contact the plugin author because there is some problem with the hook itself.

Comment: Hi @rank can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404710/woocommerce-display-remaining-item-stock-quantity-in-new-order-emails-from-post